# $E$ measurable set and $m(E\cap I)\le \frac{1}{2}m(I)$ for any open interval, prove $m(E) =0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Ran across this problem and need some help.

Let $E$ be a measurable subset of the real numbers and suppose that for any open interval $I$ one has $m(E\cap I)\le \frac{1}{2}m(I)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Prove that $m(E)=0$.

Comment: If it's so "simple", then why are you having trouble with it?  What are your thoughts on the question?  Have you tried anything on your own and gotten stuck?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Because he is modest enough to admit he is stuck in something simple. Modesty is a virtue. I wonder what kind of person criticizes a virtue.

Comment: @Pp.. modesty is one thing, but it's another to minimize the efforts of those who might help.  Perhaps, though, I am being overly sensitive.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How do you get from an adjective to the problem to an adjective to our effort? You have some issues. And given that you are in the diametrically opposite position of "those who might help", I wonder why do you care.

Comment: @Pp.. This is not the place for such a discussion. So, I will simply agree to disagree and state that I (as well as many others on this site) frown upon [PSQ posts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18854/what-is-going-on-with-undeletion-lately/18871#18871).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Keep on frowning then. The world simply doesn't work the way you want. :)

Answer (score 5):

It is enough to prove that $m(E\cap [n,n+1])=0$ is for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. 
The same argument applies to all cases of $n$ so let's prove $m(F)=0$ where $F:=E\cap [0,1]$.

From the condition we have that $m(F)\leq 1/2$.

So, we should be able to cover $F$ with countably many intervals $I_n$ such that $m(\cup_n I_n)<1/2+1/4$. This is because the Lebesgue measure of a measurable set is (by definition) its outer measure and from the definition of outer measure the existence of such a sequence of intervals follows (recall that the outer measure is the infimum of the sums of the lengths of each covering by intervals).

Now

$$m(F)=m(\bigcup_n(F\cap I_n))\leq \sum_n m(F\cap I_n)\leq \frac{1}{2}\sum_n m(I_n)\leq 1/4+1/8$$

Again choose a new sequence of intervals covering $F$ such that their lengths add less than $1/4+1/8+1/16$. Repeating the argument we get that

$$m(F)\leq 1/8+1/16+1/32$$

Continuing in this way we get that, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

$$m(F)\leq \sum_{k=n}^{2n}2^{-k}.$$

But the right-hand side tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ (because $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-k}$ is convergent).

Therefore $m(F)=0$.

Comment: Can I ask why is it enough to prove for $[n, n + 1]$ and not $(n, n + 1)$? I know there is very little difference.

Comment: @Hawk It is also enough to prove it using $(n,n+1)$. The union of the points being left out in that way has measure zero ($m(\mathbb{Z})=0$).

Comment: thanks. From this technique, is it also okay to replace them with clopen sets $(n, n + 1]$? It looks like it is.

Comment: @Hawk Yes, is is OK. Any countable covering of the reals with finite intervals is enough.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Lebesgue Density Theorem.