# Can $[0,1]$ be partitioned with the following property?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $I:= [0,1]$.

Does there exist a partition $\{I_1,I_2\}$ of $I$ such that for all Borel subsets $A$ of $[0,1]$ we have:

$$ \mu (I_1 \cap A) = \frac{1}{2} \mu(A) = \mu (I_2 \cap A)$$

where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I may be misreading something. If the measure of A is less than 1/2, isn't there no hope?

Comment: I made a mistake, it should read $1/2  \cdot \mu(A)$.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1088967/26489). The measures of both $I_1$ and $I_2$ would have to be zero. But that can't be.

Comment: So the answer is no. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A complementary fact due to Kunen: If $m:\mathcal{P}([0, 1]) \to [0, 1]$ is *any* total extension of Lebesgue measure, then there is some $X \subseteq [0, 1]$ such that for every Borel $B \subseteq [0, 1]$, $m(X \cap B) = m(B)/2$.